# Target rich clients with Adwords?

Tags: google-search, google-ads

I have been using adwords for about 10 years. My business involves targeting rich and wealthy people who can buy a real estate of 1 million or above in european countries.

i hate to admit that i was never successful in finding such clients online. I have spent over $50,000 all these 6 years, still i have had only 3 or 4 clients in these years, which is a catastrophic failure for me. Lots of money wasted.

What is wrong with adwords? 
Is there a way to reach such high end clients?

This is what i did:

1. I tried to target specific countries, where there is high income.
2. I did some research it seems organic traffic to website brings such high end client inquiries (not through adwords).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, high net-worth clients are less likely to be attracted by any form of online advertising. These clients prefer the personal face-to-face interaction in more "exclusive circles" with people they trust. Building up trust takes a lot of time and the right contacts. You normally have to get introduced to such circles. In the real estate sector in Central Europe, it is more common to build a relationship with a local estate agent, who will look for the right properties on behalf of the client and makes purchasing suggestions.

As your figures indicate that your AdWords-strategy is not working, I see the following possibilities:

- You find a niche within the high net-worth segment, e.g. you could target buyers interested in exclusive holiday apartments in the Mediterranean Sea / you target a specific group of foreigners who are interested in buying a flat in city XYZ outside their own country.
- You target real estate agents that act on behalf of high net-worth clients.
- You lower your expectations and focus on upper-middle class buyers interested in real-estate as these might be more receptive to Google AdWords advertising.

Comment: Thank you. Cant agree more. There is much more than to online advertising :J